# How to look at deleted answers on my question?

Tags: support, answers

I would like to know how to view the deleted answers on [my question](https://superuser.com/q/1723145/1678725). How do I do that?

I don't need to view deleted answers on other peoples' questions—just my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need >10k rep, or ask someone with >10k rep or a mod.

[image]